# how to send email using asp.net and html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a contact.html page where i have textboxex page for username,email,phone,subject, message and a submit button.

```
<form class="contact-page-form-1">
      <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Name*" id="username" required>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" id="email" required>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Num" id="phone" required>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" required>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message..." id="message"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group">
                  <button class="theme-btn btn-style-one" onclick="javascript:SendMail()" type="submit" name="submit-form">Send Message</button>
          </div>

      </div>
</form>
```

when we click on the button the javascript function is called where i Called a webmethod which is in VisionMail.aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendMail() {
        var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var URL = "VisionMail.aspx?uname=" + uname + "&email=" + email + "&ph=" + phone + "&sub=" + subject + "&msg=" + message + "&count=India";
                    window.open(URL);
    }
</script>
```

My WebMethod used for sending mail is in VisionMail.aspx as following:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uname = Request.QueryString["uname"].ToString();
        string email = Request.QueryString["email"].ToString();
        string phone = Request.QueryString["ph"].ToString();
        string subject = Request.QueryString["sub"].ToString();
        string message = Request.QueryString["msg"].ToString();
        string country = Request.QueryString["count"].ToString();

        string close = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                            window.returnValue = true;
                            window.close();
                            </script>";


        using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("info@xyz.com");
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = "Mr. " + uname + "<br/>" + "Email ID : " + email + " Phone No. " + phone + "<br/> <h4>He/She is Sending Message From Contact Page (" + country + "). <br/>" + message;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
            {
                try
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "abc123");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);

                    base.Response.Write(close);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    base.Response.Write(close);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code is well on local system and mail is going but when i publish it on server it does not work and when i click on button to send mail, the mail does not go and the page which the webmethod present is downloaded. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: I am not sure but when you enable SSL shouldn't the port be 465?? I think if not then the problem may be network related...like proxy or anything..Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

> using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
>   {
>
> try
>       {
>
> ```
>   smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("visioncomn@gmail.com", "visioncomptel123");
>
>   smtp.EnableSsl = smtp.Port == 587 || smtp.Port == 465;
>
>   smtp.Send(mail);
>
>   base.Response.Write(close);
> ```
>
> }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>          base.Response.Write(close);
>     }
>   }